# Excel FILTER formula using spill range in criteria

Tags: excel, filter

I'm having trouble getting the FILTER formula to work using a spillover range.  Here's is a sample scenario:

[image]

I have a spillover range in E2 that gives me a list of numbers I would like to lookup.  The lookup table is A2:B6. If I use the following formula in F2 and drag it down to F4, everything works perfectly:

```
   =LET(ProductFound, UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$6, $A$2:$A$6=E2, "Nothing found")),
    IFS(ROWS(ProductFound)>1, "There are two products with the same SKU #",
        ProductFound="Nothing found", "No Such Product with SKU #",
        TRUE, ProductFound))
```

However, I would like F2 to be a spillover formula that automatically matches the size of E2 so I do not have to perform any manual dragdown but I can't figure a way. When I change the formula to use the spillover range operator I only get **#N/A** in F2:

```
   =LET(ProductFound, UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$6, $A$2:$A$6=E2#, "Nothing found")),
    IFS(ROWS(ProductFound)>1, "There are two products with the same SKU #",
        ProductFound="Nothing found", "No Such Product with SKU #",
        TRUE, ProductFound))
```

Can anyone help with a solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BYROW:

```
=BYROW(E2#,LAMBDA(a,LET(ProductFound, UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$6, $A$2:$A$6=a, "Nothing found")),
IFS(ROWS(ProductFound)>1, "There are two products with the same SKU #",
    ProductFound="Nothing found", "No Such Product with SKU #",
    TRUE, ProductFound))))
```

[image]